# android.support.v7.appCompactActivity is not supported

Tags: android

Not supported library

[image: View here],

I had downloaded all the sdk tools in android studio ....but `android.support.v7.appcompactactivity` library is not set in dependencies.if i try to set its generate error.and i had already set theme

[image: View here]

Comment: Click on `Install repository and sync project` then Studio will automatically download and setup it for you.

Comment: `plz find me solution` **NO**.

Comment: **failed to resolve** is a networking issue, not an Android, or Android Studio problem. Showing the Gradle files as text, not images

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using + with the version. Use the exact version name then download and sync.

Comment: Regardless of the plus, it looks like Gradle is not downloading anything

Comment: Plz share you build.gradle as a text file or paste its complete code

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading your

```
 buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```